# Text field format property - Phone number with extension: Populates right to left instead of left to right

Tags: ms-access

Using MSAccess 2016 64 bit with a SQL Server Express back end. I'm trying to store unformatted phone numbers in an nvarchar field.

Stored Value

```
123456789054321
```

Expected display format

```
123-456-7890 x.54321
```

In order to do so I need to ensure they display correctly on forms and reports.

For some reason, the format property populates from the right to the left. When I type:

```
1234567890
```

It displays

```
 - 1-2345 x.67890
```

While I expect

```
123-456-7890 x.
```

These are the formats I have tried:

```
&&&\-&&&\-&&&&" x."&&&&&;"(123-456-7890 x.12345)"

@@@\-@@@\-@@@@" x."&&&&&;"(123-456-7890 x.12345)"
```

What do I need to do to get it to display properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a bang in front:

```
!@@@\-@@@\-@@@@" x."&&&&&;"(123-456-7890 x.12345)"
```

The format may need adjustment though after this.

Comment: That was it. I saw reference to that on MSDN for the input mask, and even tried it, but in retrospect at the wrong end of the format. Now to see if my users freak out or not.

Comment: Many users dislike inputmasks. You may have to add some code to control the behaviour of the cursor when users click the textbox.

Comment: yes and I can appreciate why. I'm refraining from the input mask for that reason. In this case, when I was researching my goal there was a mention of using ! to reverse entry for the input mask, but I didn't see anything about it for Formats.